# NotSerializableException при получении объекта

Tags: java

Есть клиент (`Login`), отсылающий через класс соединения (`clentCon`) серверу объект (`objRequest`). Сервер (`ServerWindow`) получает объект (для каждого клиента создаётся свой `echoThread`), работает с ним, собирает ответный объект (`objResponse`) и отправляет его клиенту. В классе `objResponse` 3 переменных (`ResultSet`, `int`, `String`, все имеют значения по умолчанию, конструкторы просто присваивают новые значения двум из них), класс `implements Serializable`.

В данный момент клиент обращается к серверу в двух местах. В одном ("проверка соединения") в возвращаемом объекте меняются `int` и `String` и всё работает нормально. Во втором (подразумевает запрос к бд) должны меняться `ResultSet` и `String`, но получаю следующее:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at logic.echoThread.run(echoThread.java:60)
```

со стороны сервера и

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at keyringWindows.Login.checkPassword(Login.java:257)
at keyringWindows.Login$3.actionPerformed(Login.java:151)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at logic.clientCon.run(clientCon.java:36)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at logic.echoThread.run(echoThread.java:60)
```

со стороны клиента.

Насколько я могу судить, проблема где-то в echoThread

```
public class echoThread extends Thread
{
    protected Socket soc = null;
    private ObjectInputStream objins = null;
    private ObjectOutputStream objouts = null; 
    private Connection con = null;
    public JTextPane tp;

    public echoThread(Socket soc, Connection con, JTextPane tp)
    {
        this.soc = soc;
        this.con = con;
        this.tp = tp;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            objins = new ObjectInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
            objouts = new ObjectOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
            while(true)
            {
                try
                {
                    objRequest request = (objRequest) objins.readObject();
                    sleep(250);
                    String type = request.getType();
                    tp.setText(tp.getText() + String.format("Получен запрос типа: %s\n", type));
                    objResponse resp = null;
                    if(type.equals("select"))
                    {
                        Statement st = con.createStatement();
                        resp = new objResponse(st.executeQuery(request.getQuery()), type);
                        st.close();
                    }
                    else if(type.equals("check"))
                    {
                        resp = new objResponse(123,"checked");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(request.getQuery());
                        resp = new objResponse(statement.executeUpdate(), type);
                        statement.close();
                    }

                    objouts.writeObject(resp);
                    objouts.flush();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ошибка подключения.\n" + ex.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                tp.setText(tp.getText() + "Клиент отключился\n");
                soc.close();
                objins.close();
                objouts.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ошибка подключения. Серверное приложение будет выключено.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Прошу помочь разобраться в чём дело.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `ResultSet`, котоый вы пытаетесь засунуть в `ObjectOutputStream` в рамках объекта `objResponse` не сериализуем, поэтому его нельзя (простите за тавтологию) сериализовать, то есть, записать в `ObjectOutputStream`. Отсюда проблема на клиенте: так как сервер не смог записать данные в ответ, на стороне клиента вылез `NullPointerException`. [Хорошая статья про сериализацию в Java](http://www.skipy.ru/technics/serialization.html).

Вам стоит пересмотреть протокол обмена данными между клиентом и сервером. Зачем сервер отдаёт необработанный `ResultSet`? Лучше будет на сервере вытащить из него нужные данные, сложить их в какой-нибудь сериализуемый объект и только потом передавать на клиент.

Ещё: закрывать `statement` нужно в блоке `finally`. Если в вашем коде произойдёт ошибка при исполнении SQL запроса, `statement` останется незакрытым, и у вас будет утечка памяти.

**Обновление**

Всё же лучше рассмотреть вариант с предоставлением результата в виде объекта конкретного класса. Вообще, если вы не пишете приложение, чья цель - позволить пользователю исполнять любые SQL-запросы на сервере, лучше будет, если клиент не будет знать, как и откуда получаются данные. Если вам так не хочется писать отдельный класс для каждого запроса, используйте `List<Map<String, Object>>`, но никак не `ResultSet`.

Comment: Понятно. Немного погуглил и нашёл некий `CachedRowSetImpl`, который, судя по описанию, является сериализуемым расширением `ResultSet`. Поскольку у меня планируется _много_ разных запросов к базе, и расписывать в отдельные классы (или один особенно громоздкий) каждый вариант не хотелось бы, можно ли использовать его?